# Phantom Wallet is displaying animated NFTs as greyed out images or static

Tags: nft, phantom, magiceden

We are currently testing animated versions of the Magnum AI NFTs on the google chrome browser!

Phantom wallet is displaying some of the GIFs with a grey image place holder or an outdated non-animated image. We have updated several NFTs to animated GIFs and sometimes it takes 24+ hours to update correctly or they continue to have greyed out or static image placeholders instead.

Solscan of an NFT displaying correctly in Phantom - https://solscan.io/token/9W4K6xdCaJRSpMW6uBTMy34X9NwRnUkG5isCNm1PMpV7

Solscan of an NFT displaying incorrectly in Phantom -
https://solscan.io/token/9pXsTJQv2TBjWLuaho4jZ31TWYjHZF5mxpUGiaxTU8UX

The NFT is showing as an animated GIF IMMEDIATELY on Solscan and Hyperspace. Is this just a caching issue with Phantom and Magic Eden that is out of our control?

Is there anything that we can do to work on this issue from our end?

Please Advise,

Thank you[image: greyed out images]

Comment: it might be an issue with the way your metadata is set up

Comment: Okay so I found that Magic Eden is loading a png that doesn’t exist for the one that does not work. So it’s using the wrong image. I’m looking into the metadata to see if something is wrong there

Comment: Thank you for the reply, please let us know if you find anything wrong with the Metadata. That would be greatly appreciated.

We think the problem with Magic Eden is related to their image provider being compromised the other day. That 3rd party service caches their images. 

Same with Phantom, we believe it's a caching issue, and it takes time to update. It's just problematic when it takes 24 hours or more to update sometimes.

Comment: Hey yeah, I didn't find anything strange. I think your theory about the cache not being updated makes sense. since its using the image link from before it was animated

Comment: also it looks like its working now